# How to upload profile picture with blobID during signup in QuickBlox?

Tags: iphone, ios, quickblox

I have problem image uploading during signup.There is a blobID property.can you tell me how we can generate blobid uniquely to new user.I checked with dummy integer value. I found error this blobid not associate with this userid. Please provide me better solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

You should do next tasks:

1. Sign Up user
2. Sign In user
3. Create blob and Upload file - you will receive **blobID** of new file
4. Update user's **blobID** field - just set **blobID** from step 3

Comment: how to send picture as an attachment to offline users in quickblox?

Comment: I had tried above answer. I am not able to sign in with user credentials(who is not owner) I can upload file from application "content". And file is associated only with owner only. However when I set the ID of file from application "content" to user who is not owner then I am facing error like "Blob does not belong to current user". Please guide me how can I set blob id for the users who is not application owner means they are belonging application "users" sections. @Igor Khomenko

Answer (score 1):

Using SWIFT. The popUp function lets the user know they have been successfully added.

```
func addUser() {

    // add new user

    let newUser:QBUUser = QBUUser()

    newUser.password = pwTxt.text
    newUser.fullName = unTxt.text
    newUser.email = emTxt.text


    QBRequest.signUp(newUser, successBlock: { (response) in

        self.popUp("Signup Success!", msg:"You are now signed up!", button1: "OK!")

        // You must be logged in to upload an avatar/image file        
        QBRequest.logIn(withUserEmail: self.emTxt.text!, password: self.pwTxt.text!, successBlock: { (response: QBResponse, user) in

            QBRequest.tUploadFile(imgData, fileName: "image.png", contentType: "image/png", isPublic: true, successBlock: { (response, blob) in

             }, statusBlock: { (request, status) in
                        print("Upload Succcess!")

             }, errorBlock: { (response) in
                        print("Upload Failure!")
             })

         }, errorBlock: { (response: QBResponse) in
                    print("Sign In Failed")
         })

         }, errorBlock: { (response) in
                    print("Error in SignUp")

         })
 }


func popUp (_ title: String, msg: String, button1: String){


    print("\(title)")
    print("\(msg)")

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "\(title)", message: "\(msg)", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "\(button1)", style: .default, handler: {
        action in
        alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }))

}
```